# Solving number divisibility problem using cardinal number of sets!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, divisibility

How many natural numbers $n<10^6$ are divisible by $7$ but not with $10,12$ and $25$?

*Theorem:* Let $n,k\in \mathbb{N}$ and $k\leq n$, then in the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$ we have exactly $\left \lfloor \dfrac{n}{k} \right \rfloor$  numbers divisible by $k$.

$S=\{1,2,...,10^6\}$

$A_7$ - set of all numbers from $S$ divisible by $7$

$A_{10}, A_{12}, A_{25}$ - sets of all numbers from $S$ divisible by $10,12$ and $25$

The solution of our problem is the cardinal number of the following set: $| A_7 \cap \overline{A_{10}} \cap \overline{A_{12}} \cap \overline{A_{25}}|$

Let $T=\overline{A_{10}} \cap \overline{A_{12}} \cap \overline{A_{25}}$

Using the following formula:
$|\overline{A}\cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C}|=|S|-|A|-|B|-|C|+|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|$

and the fact that

$|A_7|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{7}\right \rfloor=142857  $

$|A_{10}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{10}\right \rfloor=100000 $

$|A_{12}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{12}\right \rfloor=83333 $

$|A_{25}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{25}\right \rfloor=40000 $

$|A_{10}\cap A_{12}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{60}\right \rfloor=16666 $

$|A_{10}\cap A_{25}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{50}\right \rfloor=20000 $

$|A_{12}\cap A_{25}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{300}\right \rfloor=3333 $

$|A_{10}\cap A_{12} \cap A_{25}|=\left \lfloor \dfrac{10^6}{300}\right \rfloor=3333 $

we get that $|T|=81333$.

We have to calculate $|A_7 \cap T|=|S|- |\overline{A_7}\cup \overline{T}|$

This is how far I got!

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: Have you tried something ?

Comment: Thank you very much, I will edit my question right away.

Comment: Why don't you start by writing down the first 200 numbers or so and start checking off the ones that work, and look for a pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**:The cardinal you want to find is the cardinal of the set $A_7\backslash(A_{10}\cup A_{12}\cup A_{25})$ for which you can use the following formula:

$$|T|=|\overline{A}\cap \overline{B} \cap \overline{C}|=|A_7|-|A|-|B|-|C|+|A\cap B|+|A\cap C|+|B\cap C|-|A\cap B\cap C|$$

with $A=A_7\cap A_{10}=A_{70}$, $B=A_7\cap A_{12}$ and $C=A_7\cap A_{25}$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I understand everything now (Y)